# How to simplify awkward concurrency code?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Basically this code does http requests and if a http request times out, it resets the wifi connection (have to do that sometimes, it's just the way it is, I could just as well be something else non-android related instead of "reset wifi connection").

The following special cases have to be considered:

- if 1 or many threads are currently doing http requests, do not allow another thread to reset wifi connection yet
- if 1 thread is already currently resetting wifi connection, and another thread is about to reset wifi connection, send the latter thread directy to retry http request instead (when former thread finished resetting wifi)
- do not do http requests when wifi connection is currently being reset
- => only 1 thread can fix wifi connection at a time, but multiple threads can initiate http requests simutaneosly

It is giving me a headache.

Here is my code so far. What can I improve?

```
static int requestsActive = 0;
protected int requestTry = 0;
static final int maxTrys = 2;
static final ReentrantLock wifiLock = new ReentrantLock();

public void evaluate() throws Exception {
try {
    requestTry++;
    while (wifiLock.isLocked()) // no not start new http request while wifi is being fixed
        Thread.sleep(400);
    requestsActive++; //increment so that another thread that wants to fix wifi knows it has to wait
    response = httpClient.execute(requestBase);
    requestsActive--; // when == 0 wifi can be fixed if it needs to
} catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
    requestsActive--; //same as above (for exception case)
    if (requestTry == maxTrys)
        throw new ConnectTimeoutException("maxTrys reached");
    if (!wifiLock.tryLock()) //another thread is currently fixing wifi, no need to do it myself
        evaluate(); // ...so start a new http request
    while (requestsActive > 0) // wait until no more threads are in the http request section above
        Thread.sleep(400);
    WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) App.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    resetWifi(wifiMan); //reset android wifi, nothing special
    wifiLock.unlock();
    evaluate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't guarantee this will work as I do not have the Android simulator installed and threw it together pretty quickly. Hopefully it will prove helpful to you at least as a concept to build off of though. Basically it uses a Semaphore to allow a limited number of requests to be attempted at a time, and when the connection times out it will acquire all of the permits for the semaphore which will block any new requests from being made while the wifi gets reset. This leverages concurrency code already existing in the Java code base so you don't have to re-implement any of it yourself.

You can see the JavaDoc for Semaphores [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

```
static final int MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 10;
static final Semaphore httpRequestsLock = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, true);

public void evaluate() throws Exception {
    Foo requestBase = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    httpRequestsLock.acquire();
    try{
        response = httpClient.execute(requestBase);
    }
    catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        httpRequestsLock.release();
        httpRequestsLock.acquire(MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS); // Blocks until all current requests are done
        WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) App.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        resetWifi(wifiMan); //reset android wifi, nothing special
        httpRequestsLock.release(MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS);
        evaluate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the answer can't get any better, thank you. Did not know about semaphores. And they seem to be made for this kind of stuff.